# Service workers for storing an access token in browser with OAuth flow in Next JS app?

Tags: next.js, oauth, service-worker, web-worker

Our team is struggling to choose between Service Workers and HTTPonly cookies + NextAuth.
Storing a token in a service worker seems like a new and secure way, but I have not found a lot of examples of that. If you have an experience of using service workers for storing access token and challenges you faced, please share!

Thank you.If you have an experience of using service workers for storing access token and challenges you faced, please share! Thank you.